# "Средняя школа-интернат" или "средняя школа -- интернат"?

Tags: пунктуация

средняя школа-интернат или средняя школа -- интернат?

Или то и другое правильно? В первом случае школа-интернат является средней, а во втором средняя школа является интернатом.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
В сочетаниях с приложением, если одна из частей содержит пробел, вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире: школа-интернат, но средняя школа – интернат.

Answer (score 2):

Это *составное* существительное женского рода и устоявшийся термин. Склоняются обе части слова, но смысловая связь с прилагательным (здесь "средняя") подчёркивается согласованием его по падежу и роду с первой частью составного слова - ведь и у вас нет сомнения на этот счёт. Слово это определяет разновидность школы, а не интерната: это школа закрытого ("интернатного") типа, а не интернат со школой при нём; не бывает "средних интернатов", потому и согласование с частью "школа". То есть, часть  "интернат" имеет подчинённый смысл (её можно трактовать и как сокращение от "интернатного типа"). В случае тире (либо скобок при "интернате") выражение уместно разве что в каком-то диалоге с уточнением, где фигурируют школы разного уровня образования:

- В средней школе - интернате [= я имею в виду интернат - из тех средних школ, которые упоминались]...

Поэтому правильно: **средняя школа-интернат**.

Comment: *Поэтому правильно: средняя школа-интернат.* - совершенно не понимаю логику. "Средняя школа" - вот это термин. и школа-интернат - термин. А "средняя школа-интернат" - это смешение зеленого с горячим. А где и кем он стоялся-то? Самое интересное, что дальнешим текстом Вы сами себя опровергаете. "Средняя" - разновидность школы, а не интерната, как вы совершенно верно пишете. Из этого как раз и следует, что дефис будет неправилен.

Comment: Плюс ко всему именно тире лучше передает подчиненность  второй части, ср: *старший лейтенант  -- инженер*, *Заслуженный артист -- исполнитель*, *Почетный академик -- филолог*. Ваш вариант с дефисом явно выбивается из этого списка.

Answer (score 2):

На практике применяется дефисное написание, что можно объяснить тем,  что школа-интернат рассматривается **как единое словосочетание терминологического характера**.

Оно может входить в составные названия различных учебных заведений, в том числе иметь согласованные и несогласованные определения: средняя школа-интернат, средняя школа-интернат МИД,  средняя образовательная школа-интернат № 11 с углубленным изучением китайского языка и др.

Answer (score 0):

Одиночное приложение обычно присоединяется к определяемому нарицательному существительному посредством дефиса, например: город-герой, гвардейцы-миномётчики, девочки-подростки, зима-волшебница, злодей-тоска.

Примечание 2. В некоторых случаях возможно **дефисное написание и при наличии пояснительного слова (определения),** которое по смыслу может относиться или ко всему сочетанию (известный экспериментатор-изобретатель, ловкий акробат-жонглёр), или только к определяемому слову **(оригинальный художник-самоучка, моя соседка-педагог)**, или только к приложению (женщина-врач с большим стажем). **Однако в этих случаях обычно возможна двоякая пунктуация;** ср.: Лекцию прочитает известный **профессор-химик. – Лекцию прочитает известный профессор, химик.**

См.: Розенталь.Д.Э. Справочник по правописанию и стилистике.

Answer (score 0):

По грамматике и орфографии-пунктуации все верно, оба случая возможны.

С точки зрения же логики (и отчасти даже здравого смысла) - оба варианта неуклюжи и являются на мой вкус порождением канцелярита, к которому мы начали привыкать. Ну что может быть в интернате такого "среднего", даже если он совмещен со школой?! а если средняя только школа, то с какого боку тут вообще интернат? так что "оба хуже".

Но в первом случае есть еще грамматическая нечеткость, при дефисном написании акцент делается на интернат (а он здесь всего лишь приложение) - и хочется даже сказать "средний школа-интернат". 
так что из двух зол я за второе, написание через тире, вопреки даже сложившейся практике, но ради хоть какого смыслового порядка.

Comment: *>> при дефисном написании акцент делается на интернат (а он здесь всего лишь приложение)*

Кем делается?

*>> и хочется даже сказать "средний школа-интернат"*

Кому хочется? Опрос проводили? Вам хочется? Ну и что?

Comment: *Кому хочется?* - Мне хочется. А вы всегда опрос проводите, если вам, пардон, по маленькому хочется? А если по большому? И не надо так жирно троллить, господин хороший, это скучно.

Comment: Я реагирую исключительно на ваши не вполне адекватные ответы. Один "канцелярит" чего стоит. Да и "что в интернате среднего" – тоже маленький шедевр. Зарапортовались слегка... Скучно не скучно, зато правда.

Comment: Я давно уже не интересуюсь, на что вы там себе  реагируете. Это Ваши тараканы. Но "неадекватность" ответа доказывают адекватными методами, а не хамством и троллингом. Впоочем, можете развлекаться, если Вам делать больше нечего ))).

Comment: Теперь по сути. *Один "канцелярит" чего стоит* - не зарапотавались, милейший?  *Да и "что в интернате среднего"* – тоже маленький шедевр. Зарапортовались слегка...* - одно это чего стоит. ))) Вы можете продолжать умничать, только это действительно скучно.